# Kernel copy_to_user in a for loop

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, kernel

I had a hard time understanding how copy_to_user works. Let's say I have an array that looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

And I want to print it like this (with a `\t` in between)

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
```

Now in a for loop it would look something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    if(i%3==0 && i>0)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%d\t", array[i]);
}
```

But how would I achieve this with copy_to_user? My code currently looks like this, but it doesn't work.

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    if(i%3==0 && i>0)
    {
        if(raw_copy_to_user(buf,"\n",1))
        {
            return -EFAULT;
        }
    }
    if(raw_copy_to_user(buf,array[i],1))
    {
        return -EFAULT;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I am indeed writing a driver and this is being used in the file operations read function. The function call looks like this:

```
ssize_t driver_read(struct file *filp, char* buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos);
```

Comment: Are you writing a driver? Where does `buf` come from?

Comment: `copy_to_user` works similar to `memcpy` except that the destination is a user space address and the return value is the number of bytes that could not be copied (so the copied amount is the length in bytes minus the return value).

Comment: @persuez i have edited the question and added the function call.